# Generic inheritance Issue

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have a couple interfaces to support our post processing of entities:

WorkFlowProcessor

```
public interface WorkFlowProcessor {
   void PostProcess(List<WorkFlowStrategy> strategies);
}
```

WorkFlowAction

```
public class WorkFlowAction implements WorkFlowProcessor{
   ...
   ...
    public void PostProcess(List<WorkFlowStrategy> strategies){
      for(WorkFlowStrategy strategy : strategies){
           strategy.process(this)
      }
    }
}
```

WorkFlowStrategy

```
public interface WorkFlowStrategy {
   void process(WorkFlowProcessor itemToProcess);
}
```

TicketWorkFlowStrategy

```
public class TicketWorkFlowStrategy implements WorkFlowStrategy {
   ...
   ...
   @Overried
   public void process(WorkFlowAction action){   //must override or implement a supertype method
       // do a lot of processing
   }
}
```

I'm trying to figure out why I cannot get it to compile with the `WorkFlowAction` class.  Normally this works just fine.  Any thoughts on how I can get this to run correctly?

Comment: That's because you've got to declare it with the same signature as the method in the interface: `<T extends WorkFlowProcessor> void process(T itemToProcess)`.

Comment: As an aside, that type variable is useless; you may as well just declare it as `void process(WorkflowProcessor itemToProcess)`.

Comment: @AndyTurner, before I posted this question I tried everything you suggested.  It still does not work without creating many `process` methods that accept the concrete implementation

Comment: I got around the issue by passing in a `WorkFlowAction` Id (Long), rather than the type.  I'll query the DB for the types later when I need to know.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you've got to declare it with the same signature as the method in the interface:

```
<T extends WorkFlowProcessor> void process(T itemToProcess)
```

Declaring the method like this in the interface *doesn't* mean you can specialize implementations of it for more specific parameters. This method has to accept *any* `WorkflowProcessor`.

Because of that fact, the type variable here is pretty useless: you may as well just declare it thus in the interface, which makes it cleaner to implement too:

```
void process(WorkflowProcessor itemToProcess);
```

Method-level type variables aren't actually useful unless you doing one or more of the following:

- Returning the same type as a non-generic parameter
- Constraining a generic parameter to be related either to another parameter or the return type.

---

If you want to specialize the `process` method for a particular subclass of `WorkflowProcessor`, you have to put this on the `interface`:

```
public interface WorkFlowStrategy<T extends WorkFlowProcessor> {
  void process(T itemToProcess);
}
```

Then:

```
public class TicketWorkFlowStrategy implements WorkFlowStrategy<WorkflowAction> {
  @Override
  public void process(WorkFlowAction action){
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes this works, but now your strategy is locked in and cannot dynamically use other implementations for that interface

Comment: @Dan yep. That's because of the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle): all subclasses must accept parameters *at least* as general as their superclasses. You can't be more specific in subclasses (and Java doesn't accept contravariant parameter types, so you can't be less specific either).

Comment: I'm staring at her book right now... I'll check it out

Answer (score -1):

The implication being made by the `process` method as defined in the `WorkFlowStrategy` interface is that implementations should be able to accept any `WorkFlowProcessor` as an argument to the method.  The generic definition you added to this method does nothing to change this.

In your case, the generic definition probably belongs on the interface level, not on the method level.  You can then be explicit about what types can be supported.